# How to detect that a text is wrapped in a label?

Tags: c#, winforms, label, multiline, word-wrap

I want to detect a text in my label is single or multiline. Can I do it in a more plain way than

```
TextRenderer.MeasureText(label.Text, font, label.Size).Height > TextRenderer.MeasureText("a", font).Height
```

Comment: Why not `label.Height > TextRenderer.MeasureText("a", font).Height` ?
Anyway, I don't see any other way than yours.

Comment: @Fabske, I expect `label.Height` may be bigger, like some kind of margin, etc. I'm not sure by the way.

Comment: You're surely right, but the margin is probably a fixed value, so you could include it in the code itself. If you execute the code once, your code is fine. But if performance is a problem, removing one call to ´TextRenderer.MeasureText´ could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Only "cheat" ways like your.
E.g.

```
bool multiline = label.Height - label.Padding.Top - label.Padding.Bottom > label.Font.Size*2;
```